# Matplotlib giving some errors while ploting a graph from file

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

So, here I'm trying to plot a graph using the coordinates that are provided in a file. I'm opening the file and setting the coordinates in an array to feed the array as in put to the graph.

Code:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=[]
y=[]

readFile=open("coordinates.txt","r")
data = readFile.read().split("\n")

print(data)

for i in data:
    val = i.split(",")
    x.append(int(val[0]))
    y.append(int(val[1]))

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Output:

```
['3,22', '5,16', '-2,8', '10,43', '4,0', '']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nishantsikri/matplotlib from file.py", line 14, in <module>
    x.append(int(val[0]))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have trailing spaces in your file. Use [`strip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) to remove trailing spaces.

```
data = readFile.read().strip().split("\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have an empty line at the end of your file. One would need to check for that an not append it to the lists.

However, it seems the complete code can be condensed to

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x,y = np.genfromtxt("coordinates.txt", unpack=True, delimiter=",")
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

This would also automatically take care of the empty line.